# increasing sample size while keeping sample features

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to generate a collection of 173056 samples following the distribution in the picture, [image: picture]

but the following image was obtained plotting 6120 samples. 
Is there a way to keep this distribution while increasing the sample size?

Comment: Is this a distribution, or are those samples from the some sort of stochastic process?

Comment: Those are temperatures registered, so rather a stochastic sample.

Comment: You could choose to upsample the signal by interpolating between existing points. Not sure that's what you're looking for: and it'll be hard to say what interpolation kernel would work best and maintain your "distribution".

Answer (score 0):

Taking the problem reverse way, 173056 is about the number of temperature measures you make in a year if you do a mesure each 3 minutes.

And what you have is 6120 points, that is a point each 90 minutes. The best thing you can do is probably a linear  interpolation.

A (very simplified) model of temperature:

```
Ta=6120
Tj=Ta/365
Tp=20-10*cos(2*pi/Ta*tp)-10*cos(2*pi/Tj*tp)

tp=arange(6120)
Tp=20-10*cos(2*pi/Ta*tp)-10*cos(2*pi/Tj*tp)
```

and the interpolation:

```
t=numpy.linspace(0,6120-1,173056)
T=numpy.interp(t,tp,Tp)
```

Zoom :

```
plot(tp[:4],Tp[:4],'ro',t[:90],T[:90],'b+')
```

[image]